# Encode byte string in utf8

Tags: python, utf-8

How do I encode a byte string with non-ascii bytes into the utf8 format? For example:

```
x = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(numpy.random.rand(10, 10)))

# What to do here?
y = x.encode('utf8')
```

This will give me an error saying that some bytes are not in range(128). What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Encoding converts a unicode string to a sequence of bytes. `zlib.compress` already returns a sequence of bytes, it isn't a unicode string so encoding it as utf-8 makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide what code-points a non-ASCII byte refers to. For instance, what code-point does the byte 0xA1 refer to?

For instance, you could use any of the iso-8859-X encodings:

```
bytes = chr(161)
utf8 = bytes.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
# compare with: utf8 = bytes.decode('iso-8859-2').encode('utf-8')
```

Note that the choice of encoding makes a difference - under iso-8859-1 the byte 0xA1 is encoded as `u'\xc2\xa1'` but under iso-8859-2 it's encoded as `u'\xc4\x84'`.

Comment: Thank you, this works but after .decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8') it appears that the length of the string gets doubled. Is there an encoding which can be used in the first place, which preserves the final string length?

Comment: No. The point of utf-8 is to encode 32-bit integers in a compact way. If you don't want the length to change why are you encoding with utf-8 in the first place? Just use the original string. You need to explain why you can't just use the original string.

Comment: I have a function which takes a string as an argument, but somehow it checks if the input string is utf8 or unicode. What I have is a compressed byte string.

Comment: I tried using unicode by just passing in x.decode('iso-8859-1'), but it still complains that the unicode string has unexpected bytes.

Comment: What are you doing with `x` that gives the error? Are you trying to print it out? write it to a file?